# How to List the largerst city population for each country

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to List the largerst city population for each country
-- Use country column (not country_code), order the results by the decreasing largerst city population.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjyDl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to claim the largest city name for each country also, you can use this:

```
SELECT l.country, r.city, l.largest
FROM (
SELECT country, MAX(population) AS largest
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY country
) AS l
INNER JOIN <tablename> AS r ON l.country = r.country AND l.largest = r.population
ORDER BY largest DESC
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ran the code and it gave me 202 rows. It should give 192 rows only for some reason.

Comment: @nonobaby, why? How many distinct countries are in your dataset? How your desired result must look like? Any extra details would increase our chances to help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(population) largerst, city
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY largerst DESC, city;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.
I ran the code and it gives an error.

Comment: The query throws an error because there is a ‘city’ column that used inside  SELECT statement and not used inside GROUP BY statement.